# WPF Custom controls don't have rendering styles

Tags: c#, wpf

I create a custom control library like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhL4N.png)

KiwiButton.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KiwiWPFControl.Controls">
<Style x:Key="KiwiButtonStyle" TargetType="local:KiwiButton" >
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00AA11" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00AA88" Offset="0.5"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00AAA6" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:KiwiButton" >
                <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="15" Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers >
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="#AA00AAA6"/>
                    </Trigger >
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers >
            </ControlTemplate >
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style >
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource KiwiButtonStyle}" TargetType="local:KiwiButton"/>
```

Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/KiwiWPFControl;component/Themes/KiwiButton.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

KiwiButton.cs:

```
namespace KiwiWPFControl.Controls{
public class KiwiButton : Button
{
    static KiwiButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(KiwiButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(KiwiButton)));
    }
}
```

}

And I use this button like this

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="KiwiWPFDemo.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KiwiWPFDemo"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/KiwiWPFControl;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="KiwiWPFDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KiwiWPFDemo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:kiwi="clr-namespace:KiwiWPFControl.Controls;assembly=KiwiWPFControl"
    Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <kiwi:KiwiButton Width="200" Height="100" Content="12"/>
</Grid>
```

It compiles and runs successfully

But it shows this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psVTx.png)

How to make the style of the control take effect??

Comment: Looks like the style file is not being loaded.  But i don't know what happens

Comment: Besides what is explained in the answer, importing `/KiwiWPFControl;component/Themes/Generic.xaml` in App.xaml is not necessary and should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controltemplate, you should use templatebinding with the background. In your markup, you set the property but it is not used anywhere.

This highlights one of the things you need to bear in mind with templating.

Once you've replaced the template of a control then there is nothing there visually other than whatever you set.

You can then potentially remove the line of code sets defaultstylekeyproperty

```
<Style  TargetType="local:KiwiButton" >
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00AA11" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00AA88" Offset="0.5"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF00AAA6" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:KiwiButton" >
                <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="15" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers >
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="#AA00AAA6"/>
                    </Trigger >
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers >
            </ControlTemplate >
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style >
```

[image]

BTW the above style is all that's in my kiwibutton.xaml, I removed the line:

```
  <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource KiwiButtonStyle}" TargetType="local:KiwiButton"/>
```

As Clemens pointed out in comments.

When you set targettype you automatically get the type as an x:Key.

Some people prefer to also set that explicitly.

```
 x:Key="{x:Type local:KiwiButton}"
```

This a standard at several clients I have worked for and I am in the habit of doing this myself.

Comment: `x:Key="{x:Type local:KiwiButton}"` is redundant.

Comment: I suppose that's a matter of style, I prefer to see the key in xaml with the template rather than defined in code.

Comment: It is not set anywhere in code, the type is just the default value when TargetType is set. Setting TargetType and Key to the same value is pointless.

Comment: I mean DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata which is obviously code. But I see what you mean.

Comment: DefaultStyleKeyProperty is a totally different thing. Not sure if I need to explain it here, but it does not affect the way how TargetType and x:Key work together.